# Validar si un texto contiene una subcadena en JavaScript o jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero saber cómo puedo validar si un parámetro de entrada en una función de JavaScript contiene un substring. Tengo esto:

```js
function SweetAlert(Action) {
    if ($(Action:contains('Create')) == true) {
        swal('Buen trabajo!',
             'se creó el registro!',
             'success');
    } 
}
```

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945/1983854

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `indexOf` que te retornara -1 si no encuentra la cadena.

```js
var cadena = "hola mundo";

console.log(
  cadena.indexOf("mundo") > -1
);

console.log(
  cadena.indexOf("no esta") > -1
);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo :)

Answer (score 2):

#### String.prototype.indexOf()

Como [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf) devuelve `-1` cuando no se encuentra,

```js
~texto.indexOf(buscado)
```

será `0` (y por lo tanto *falsy*) cuando no se encuentre `buscado` dentro de `texto`.

> El operador [`~` (bitwise not)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) invierte el valor a nivel de bits.
>
> Como `-1` se representa como `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111` (en 32 bits),
> `~(-1)` se convierte en `0`.

```js
function contiene(texto, buscado) {
    return ~texto.indexOf(buscado)
}
```

---

#### String.prototype.includes() (ES6)

A partir de ECMAScript 6, se incorporó [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), que devuelve `true` o `false` <sup>(ver [compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility))</sup>.

```js
texto.includes(buscado [, posicion])
```